# Cancel http requests in angular as user keeps typing for autocomplete input

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an input with a material autocomplete component linked to it. as the user types calls are made to the server for results. its working fine as the server returns the results in order (for now) But I still would like to cancel the last call before triggering the next one. this is the method I'm using now:

```
    getCodigosPon(needle: string): Observable<any> {
      if (needle.length > 3) {
        const options = createRequestOption({ idPon: needle });
        return this.http.get<string[]>(this.codigoPonUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' });
      } else {
        return of([]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: try if this helps https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debounce

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is usual set up for input to HTTP connection.

- `debounceTime` is optional, yet nice to have.
- `switchMap` is essential, it makes it so, that the previous request will be cancelled

```
class MyComponent {
  readonly input$ = new BehaviourSubject('default input value');

  // ...

  readonly codigosPonValue$ = this.input$.pipe(
    debounceTime(300), // If you want...
    switchMap(needle => {
      if (needle.length > 3) {
        const params = createRequestOption({ idPon: needle });
        return this.http.get<string[]>(this.codigoPonUrl, { params });
      } else {
        return of([]);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

With HTML like so...

```html
<input (change)="input$.next($event.value)>
<pre>
{{codigosPonValue$ | async | json}}
</pre>
```